# Golf Round for a group of $12$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs

$12$ gentlemen wish to play $7$ rounds of golf.  They want to split into $3$ groups of $4$ and play a different group each time with as much variety as possible without playing the same individuals repetitively.  What formula would they use to accomplish this?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: I think you'll need to quantify "with as much variety as possible" to make this a well-defined mathematical problem.

Comment: I had the question wrong.  The 12 golfers want to split into 3 groups of 4.  Here is what I have so far:

Comment: 1,2,3,4| 5,6,7,8| 9,10,11,12|| 1,5,9,10| 2,6,11,12| 3,4,7,8|| 1,5,8,12| 2,7,10,11| 3,4,6,9|| 1,7,9,11| 2,4,6,8| 3,5,10,12|| 1,4,6,10| 2,3,5,7| 8,9,11,12|| 1,3,7,12| 2,8,9,12| 4,5,6,10|| 1,2,8,11| 3,5,6,12| 4,7,9,10||

Comment: I guess instead of "with as much variety as possible" I should say with the fewest amount of people repeating in groups of four.

Answer (score 1):

This question asks to find a edge covering of the complete graph $K_{12}$ using $7$ copies of $3K_4:=K_4 \cup K_4 \cup K_4$.  There are $\binom{12}{2}=66$ edges in $K_{12}$ and $7 \times 3 \times 6=126$ edges in the $7$ copies of $3K_4$.

The above suggests the "best possible" might be when $6$ edges occur once and the other $60$ occur twice.  But this is not actually achievable as we will now explain.  Let $Z$ be one copy of $3K_4$ and $H$ be some induced $K_4$ subgraph in a copy of $3K_4$ other than $Z$.   Then $Z$ and $H$ share at least one edge (by the pigeonhole principle).  Thus, if $Y$ and $Z$ are two distinct copies of $3K_4$, then they must have at least $3$ edges in common.  So there are at least $3 \times \binom{7}{2}=63$ duplicated edge-pairs.

This means the best possible is to have $9$ edges that occur once, $3$ edges to occur $3$ times and the remaining $54$ edges to occur twice (giving $54 \binom{2}{2}+3\binom{3}{2}=63$ duplicated edge-pairs).

The example below achieves this (found by a computer search in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/)).

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ] ],
[ [ 1, 2, 5, 9 ], [ 3, 6, 7, 10 ], [ 4, 8, 11, 12 ] ],
[ [ 1, 2, 6, 11 ], [ 3, 5, 8, 12 ], [ 4, 7, 9, 10 ] ],
[ [ 1, 3, 7, 11 ], [ 2, 5, 10, 12 ], [ 4, 6, 8, 9 ] ],
[ [ 1, 4, 5, 10 ], [ 2, 7, 8, 11 ], [ 3, 6, 9, 12 ] ],
[ [ 1, 6, 8, 10 ], [ 2, 4, 7, 12 ], [ 3, 5, 9, 11 ] ], 
[ [ 1, 7, 9, 12 ], [ 2, 3, 8, 10 ], [ 4, 5, 6, 11 ] ]
```

In the example you give in the comments, the pair $\{4,6\}$ occurs $4$ times, and the pairs $\{3,11\}$, $\{4,11\}$, $\{4,12\}$, $\{5,12\}$ and $\{8,10\}$ don't occur at all, so it's suboptimal.